# if else condition not met but still running the code inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, web-config

This is a really unusual issue I am having, my if else if condition is not working:
1) I am reading values from web.config

```
string validuserlist = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Quality"].ToString();
string safetylist = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Safety"].ToString();
string supervisorlist = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Supervisors"].ToString();
```

2) I am checking to see if current user is in the above list and if the workorder type = the type from the gridview:

The condition is not met at the third condition where it checks for supervisorlist I removed my user id from the web.config and I run the application it still runs the third condition. it is suppose to say you don't have permissions.

[image]

[image]

as you can see the above condition fails but it still runs that code:

[image]

[image]
please help if you need any code or logic understanding please ask before marking this question down.

here is how my condition is laid out:

```
if (validuserlist.ToLower().Trim().IndexOf(username.ToLower().Trim()) != -1 && TextBox102.Text == "Quality")
{
    CheckQuality();
    if (flag == true)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox30");
        TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox91");
        TextBox1.Enabled = true;
        TextBox2.Enabled = true;
        DetailsView1.Visible = true;
        ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
        DetailsView2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        string message = "your user id does not have permissions to signoff WorkOrders of type" + " " + TextBox102.Text + ", please contact IT Support for Permission";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
    }
}
else if (safetylist.ToLower().Trim().IndexOf(username.ToLower().Trim()) != -1 && TextBox102.Text == "Safety")
{
    CheckSafety();
    if (flag == true)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox30");
        TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox91");
        TextBox1.Enabled = true;
        TextBox2.Enabled = true;
        DetailsView1.Visible = true;
        ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
        DetailsView2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        string message = "your user id does not have permissions to signoff WorkOrders of type" + " " + TextBox102.Text + ", please contact IT Support for Permission";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
    }
}
else if (supervisorlist.ToLower().Trim().IndexOf(username.ToLower().Trim()) != -1 && TextBox102.Text == "Safety" || TextBox102.Text == "Quality" || TextBox102.Text == "General")
{
    if (flag == false)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox30");
        TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox91");
        TextBox1.Enabled = true;
        TextBox2.Enabled = true;
        DetailsView1.Visible = true;
        ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
        DetailsView2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        string message = "your user id does not have permissions to signoff WorkOrders of type" + " " + TextBox102.Text + ", please contact IT Support for Permission";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing `if` then `else` and then `else if`, and then doing more weird stuff. Check how to use `if`

Comment: As @Aidin pointed out, the structure of your if/else statement is off.  ELSE IF or ELSE can follow an IF, but if you have an ELSE it has to be the end of the If/Then/Else statement.  So start with your IF's, follow with the ELSE IF's, and end with ELSE - note: you can only have one ELSE.

Comment: @Aidin in the do something part of my code I am using another if and else condition, each if condition has a if and else within it, ill post a sample code.

Comment: @CodeMan That is irrelevant. As @Dan said, each `if` can be followed by multiple `else if` and ended with only one `else`. You must have that order. No `else if` can come after an `else`

Comment: You better add all the code and please format it to be more easily read.

Comment: @CodeMan it seems incomplete.  Can you paste the rest, please?  Also please remove the sample-code, as it depicted a completely different problem.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky yea I have all of the code posted buddy

Comment: @Aidin I have the entire code posted as you can see I need a else in each of the if clause to restrict the user out of the method if he is not in the list of users with permissions.

Comment: Still very unreadable. But atleast, the `if`/`else` statements seems to be ordered ok. I will remove my answer since it does not apply to this actual problem

Comment: @CodeMan TextBox102 doesn't have "Quality" or "General" in it?  The (OR) will require only one of those conditions to be true in order to enter that block.

Comment: @CodeMan please verify by getting back to that breakpoint and verifying TextBox102.Text's value.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky the value of the text box is "Quality"

Comment: @CodeMan So the condition is being met.  Your first AND is being completely negated by the first OR, which is enough to fulfill the condition.

Comment: You need to add parenthesis to your conditions so that the condition becomes as you want. Put parenthesis around all your OR conditions and it should be as you want it to

Comment: @DanOrlovsky so I am not in the supervisors list so that condition failed but the type of workorder matches so according to my "if" condition both conditions have to met in order to proceed so why is it proceeding is my question?

Comment: One more second, I'm explaining it in an answer in depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after some new information was discovered in the comments, we can address what is wrong with the if condition.

```
else if (supervisorlist.ToLower().Trim().IndexOf(username.ToLower().Trim()) != -1 && TextBox102.Text == "Safety" || TextBox102.Text == "Quality" || TextBox102.Text == "General")
```

This is basically saying:

> If the supervisor is in this list AND TextBox102 is equal to "Safety" run the condition.  OR if TextBox102 is equal to "Quality", run the condition.  OR if TextBox102 is equal to "General", run the condition.

It appears you want to know if the supervisor is in that list AND if the Textbox equals one of those, so as @Aidin suggests, your IF statement should look like:

```
else if (supervisorlist.ToLower().Trim().IndexOf(username.ToLower().Trim()) != -1 && (TextBox102.Text == "Safety" || TextBox102.Text == "Quality" || TextBox102.Text == "General"))
```

Notice the extra set of parenthesis around each check of the TextBox.  This turns your IF statement to:

> If the supervisor is in the List AND TextBox102 = Safety OR TextBox102 = General OR TextBox102 = Quality, run the condition.

Comment: thanks yea I saw Aidin comment and figured it out but really appreciate the help, wow I never knew a parenthesis had such an impact :)

Answer (score 1):

(edit: Actually, kind of ninja'd Dan Orlovsky here, as he had figured out the answer in comments around the same time I posted this.  His answer is more detailed.)

```
supervisorlist.ToLower().Trim().IndexOf(username.ToLower().Trim()) != -1 
    && TextBox102.Text == "Safety" 
    || TextBox102.Text == "Quality" 
    || TextBox102.Text == "General"
```

Looks like an order of operations problem.  Put parentheses around your conditions.  Like so:

```
supervisorlist.ToLower().Trim().IndexOf(username.ToLower().Trim()) != -1 
    && (TextBox102.Text == "Safety" 
        || TextBox102.Text == "Quality" 
        || TextBox102.Text == "General")
```